pixel position of hud element and mouse in unity
I'm trying to detect if a mouse if over a hud element with C# in unity.
I have hud element taking up about 1/5th of the right side of the screen.
I basically want to do
if mouse.x < hud_element.x

If I click here (the red x just a few pixels to the left of the hud panel)

I have this function (ive put a few Debug.Log to work a few things out)
        public bool is_mouse_left_of_hud() 
    {
        Vector3 mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
        float canvas_left = GameObject.Find("Canvas").GetComponent<RectTransform>().offsetMin.x;
        float main_hud_panel_left = GameObject.Find("main_hud_panel").GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition.x;
        float info_panel = GameObject.Find("info panel").GetComponent<RectTransform>().offsetMin.x;
        Debug.Log("££££££££");
        Debug.Log("mouse x pos = " + mousePos.x);
        Debug.Log("main_hud_panel_left = " + main_hud_panel_left);
        Debug.Log("canvas offsetmin x = "+canvas_left);
        Debug.Log("info_panel offset = " + info_panel);
        Debug.Log("main hud offsetmin x + canvas offsetmin x + + info_panel offset = " + ( canvas_left +main_hud_panel_left + info_panel));
        if (mousePos.x < (canvas_left + main_hud_panel_left + info_panel))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

and clicking in the red x position on the image I get this output
££££££££
mouse x pos = 1299.395
main_hud_panel_left = 331
canvas offsetmin x = 560
info_panel offset = 0
main hud offsetmin x + canvas offsetmin x + + info_panel offset = 891

The image below is showing the hud element from the editor ui.

ps)
The reason im doing this is: im using the built in OnMouseDown functions to check click detection in GameObjects. But annoyingly that works through my hud. so I need a function to check if mouse is over the hud. So I can avoid clicking through the hud
also here is the tree of objects that lead to "info panel" and their values in the inspector


Use Rect.Contains( [point] ) or equivalent.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.rect.contains?view=windowsdesktop-8.0

Using what values for my rect? my mouse is at 1200 and adding all the other values doesnt even reach that.

The HUD element looks like a Rect to me. It has a position (x,y) and dimensions (w,h). The mouse position is a point.  Answers: "Is point in rectangle". Then geometry takes you everywhere else.

youre not looking at the numbers.
that doesnt add up, otherwise just saying... if (mouse.x < hud_pos.x) would work


I need a function to check if mouse is over the hud.

if you need to know if you are clicking on a ui object or not I think IsPointerOverGameObject will help you.
if you want to know position of clicking related to screen you can use these functions:

Camera.WorldToViewportPoint:

Transforms position from world space into viewport space.
Viewport space is normalized and relative to the camera. The bottom-left of the camera is (0,0); the top-right is (1,1).


Camera.WorldToScreenPoint:

Transforms position from world space into screen space.
Screenspace is defined in pixels. The bottom-left of the screen is (0,0); the right-top is (pixelWidth,pixelHeight).


Camera.ViewportToScreenPoint:

ransforms position from viewport space into screen space.
Viewport space is normalized and relative to the camera. The bottom-left of the camera is (0,0); the top-right is (1,1).
Screenspace is defined in pixels. The bottom-left of the screen is (0,0); the right-top is (pixelWidth,pixelHeight)



